# Как сделать обводку букв

Tags: css3, html5, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать обводку букв с помощью css ?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вам нужно обводить каждую букву по отдельности или весь тест (слово)?

Comment: Если не сложно покажите 2 варианта

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border

Comment: https://codepen.io/b_atish/pen/nmzEq?editors=1100

Comment: Боюсь, что средствами css обводку каждой буквы сделать невозможно.

Comment: TOS ясно, спасибо

Comment: HamSter спасибо, как я понял обводка делается с помощью text-shadow ?

Comment: HamSter точнее text-stroke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `text-shadow`:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:3.5rem;
  
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
   color: white;
    text-shadow:
       2px  2px 0 #000,
      -1px -1px 0 #000,  
       1px -1px 0 #000,
      -1px  1px 0 #000,
       1px  1px 0 #000;
  
}
```

```html
<h1>Почувствуй атмосферу</h1>
```

Вариант с `svg`:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

svg text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  font-size:32px;
}
```

```html
<svg  width="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 100">
<text x=0 y=32 fill='white' stroke='black' stroke-width='2'>
    Почувствуй атмосферу
</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью теней, накладываете 4 тени и каждую двигаете в разные стороны

```css
div {
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: .04em 0 #000, -.04em 0 #000, 0 .04em #000, 0 -.04em #000;
}
```

```html
<div>ПОЧУВСТВУЙ АТМОСФЕРУ</div>
```

Можете также посмотреть в сторону `-webkit-text-stroke`